# Dropbox shared_link

Tags: javascript, ajax, dropbox

I'm writing code to get a link to an image file in Dropbox. However, I get a 400 error.
The error content was "Error in call to API function " sharing / create_shared_link_with_settings \ ": request body: could not decode input as JSON". I think the description method is wrong, but I don't know what's wrong.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form">
        <h3>ファイルを選択してアップロード</h3>
        <input type="file" id="file">
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var input = document.getElementById("file");

        //ダイアログでファイルが選択された時
        input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {


            //ドロップボックスのファイルAPI
            json = {
                "url": 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings',
                "raw_url": "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings",
                "type": 'post',
                "data": {
                    "{\"path\": \"/hand4.jpg\",\"settings\": {\"audience\": \"public\",\"access\": \"viewer\",\"requested_visibility\": \"public\",\"allow_download\": true}}": ""
                },
                "headers": {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer *********",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.error(data);
                }
            }
            $.ajax(json)
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The /2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings Dropbox API endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings) is an ["RPC" style](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#formats) endpoint, meaning it expects its parameters as JSON in the request body.

The error is indicating that you are not sending valid JSON in the request body.

In your code, you're attempting to set that via the `data` field in your `json` dict, which is itself a dict with one element, with the key being the escaped string of your desired parameters, and the value being an empty string. That should instead just be the JSON string of the desired parameters.

For example, you probably meant to do something like this instead:

```
            "data": JSON.stringify({"path": "/hand4.jpg","settings": {"audience": "public","access": "viewer","requested_visibility": "public","allow_download": true}}),
```